# New Lollipop BLE API does not detect all advertising packets

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-5.0-lollipop, android-bluetooth, android-ble

I have seen a few posts with the same question but I have no been able to get a solution for my problem.

I see that the callback function (onScanResult) for the new BLE API detects advertising packets from the peripheral only for the first time. I do not see the subsequent packets at all. The strange thing is that it happens only on a few devices. It does not happen on S4 running Lollipop but I have been seeing this issue on One Plus one. But I have been able to connect to the peripheral though, using Bluetooth Gatt methods.

I also start and stop the scan with a delay of about 2 seconds in between. It does seem to work fine if I use the old API on Lollipop devices but the scanning seems to be a lot slower.

```
             if (isScanning)
                    {

                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                        {

                            if(first_time)
                            {
                                first_time = false;
                                scanner = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBluetoothLeScanner();
                                settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
                                        .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY
                                        )
                                        .build();

                                filters = new ArrayList<ScanFilter>();

                            }

                   scanner.startScan(filters, settings, new scancallback());

                        }else {
                            mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                        }

                        isScanning = !isScanning;
                    }


               try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                Log.e(TAG, "MonitorThread.InterruptedException-1");
            }

         if (!isScanning) {

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

                       scanner.stopScan(new scancallback());


                    } else {

                        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);

                    }

                    isScanning = !isScanning;

                }
```

Do anyone have a solution to this? I have been breaking my head over this issue but not able to get any leads. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: did you try with another android version ??